Why do notebooks by default put symbols in Global context where they can collide with all other notebooks?
This default setting can cause subtle and difficult to find problems, such as inconsistent or incorrect answers when symbols, variables or functions in different notebooks have the same name. I speak from painful experience.
The setting to fix this, per notebook, is from the open notebook's menu
Evaluation / Notebook's default context / Unique to this notebook (instead of Global`)
You have to remember to do that every time. I haven't been able to get the solutions given in the past to make "unique to notebook" the default context to work. I am running Wolfram 14.

Because by default, notebooks share same kernel. It is the kernel which shares the symbols between different notebooks.  Do you mean you applied is-there-a-way-to-separate-variables-between-multiple-notebooks and still you see symbols shared? Did you do the update 2 in there?  open the Options Inspector etc... It should work. B ut may be something changed if you see it not working. I am also using V 14

You can find the option in the option inspector. You can set the Global Preferences for CellContext to be Notebook.

Thanks Nasser and lericr, I figured out why update 2 wasn't working for me. You must set the field to Notebook without " or .   The default is "Global`" which implies you should use "".

@LeonidShifrin Thanks for the quick response Nasser. I knew that the notebooks share a kernel, but sharing global symbols is a design decision. That is the default, but could as well be "Unique to this notebook". This is really a question for the Mathematica design team.

Many design choices bothered me but not this I think. Guess it is a matter of preference or the way one uses WL.

When I don't want notebooks to clash, I have each one use a different kernel.  Under the Evaluation menu you can add kernels with Kernel Configuration Options.  With Notebook's Kernel you can assign a Kernel to the current notebook
